# They were angry because they had waited (had been waiting) for too long

Tags: past-perfect, progressive-aspect

Inspired by a [past-perfect vs. present-perfect](http://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-10277.php) online test:

> They were angry because they **had waited** for too long.

and

> They were angry because they **had been waiting** for too long.

Are both options grammatical? 
If yes, what is the difference in meaning?

The second options seems to be more widespread, according to a quick Google search.

Is it because with **had waited**, the process of waiting might have ended before them becoming angry, and so there is a gap between their "waiting" stopped and their "angriness" started?

Comment: I think you nailed it. Their current anger is a direct result of their wait continuing until the 'present' [the moment being spoken about], so both are now running concurrently, waiting & anger. Both are perfectly grammatical to my less than expert eye, just the 2nd has the urgency of a single continuum.

Comment: both are grammatical, IMO. The latter one talks more about 'the process' **and** gives a flair of extended 'period'! BTW, welcome back! :) +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say they waited from 10:00 to 11:00 am.  It is now 1:00.  If you were saying they were angry at 11:00 while still waiting you could use either form but the second is better because it is more clear.  If you were saying they were angry at noon--after the waiting but still in the past--then you would use the first form.